# How to install a Python library in a t2.micro what requires high memory usage?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Tested with `t2.micro`/`t3.micro` and `Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS`. At first I thought it was a storage limit but I increased to 30GB.

The steps to reproduce it:

- Create the instance
- Perform update and upgrade of `apt` and `apt-get`
- Install pip with `sudo apt install python3-pip`
- `pip install sentence-transformers`

It crash when it reaches this step:

```
Downloading nvidia_cudnn_cu12-8.9.2.26-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
Collecting nvidia-cublas-cu12==12.1.3.1 (from torch>=1.6.0->sentence-transformers)
  Downloading nvidia_cublas_cu12-12.1.3.1-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (410.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╸ 410.6/410.6 MB 67.4 MB/s eta 0:00:01Killed
```

The log error:

```
Out of memory: Killed process 1211 (python) total-vm:1024532kB, anon-rss:456116kB, file-rss:2772kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:1492kB oom_score_adj:0
[  226.612189] Out of memory: Killed process 2067 (python) total-vm:996224kB, anon-rss:450684kB, file-rss:2560kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:1516kB oom_score_adj:0
```

Comment: What is the question, exactly? It requires more memory than it's available. Use a bigger instance.

Comment: @Massimo it's my first time using EC2 and I don't know if I can install it in another way, I've never had problems installing any Python library.

Comment: You could try to install in a larger instance, convert that larger instance to an image and launch that image again with a smaller image size, but if you can't even complete the install process with limited ram, it is even more unlikely that you can use that with limited RAM

Comment: @HBruijn very good idea! I want to install it because it's synced with a `Pipfile` in git, and although I'm not going to use this library, I avoid the problem of desync the `Pipfile` by this specific library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly... all of the t*.micro instances only have 1GB RAM.  Additionally, why on earth are you trying to install nvidia anything?... these are not GPU backed instances.  Additionally, pip will download the package to RAM before attempting to extract & install it.  As the package is roughly 730mb... and the OS itself takes a bit of RAM to start with... yeah. You're going to be out of RAM.

Comment: I know that is a non-sense question, but as I clarified in the comments, I don't want to use this library, just install it to maintain the `Pipfile` synced with the git repository. A clever solution provided by @HBruijn is to install it in another bigger instance, create an image, and use that image in the micro instance. Didn't know how pip worked with the memory, thanks to clarify that point.

Comment: maintaining the package would also require you to be able to re-assemble the package.  This is also a RAM intensive process... which will also run into the same problem on the flip-side.

Comment: Yes I now see the problem, It's going to be a problem in the future in any case. Thank you for your time, I think I will mark this as response, as the possible approaches won't have sense.

Comment: Good luck in your endeavors!